# Form with validation within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I create a form within an ng-repeat and have validation on each item within the ng-repeat?  This is what I've attempted but doesn't work.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <form class="form-inline" name="myForm" ng-submit="updatePerson(person)" novalidate>
            <td ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.firstName.$error.required && !myForm.firstName.$pristine }">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="person.firstName" maxlength="25" class="form-control" required />
            </td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `<form>` tag so that it is outside of the `ng-repeat`. You need to do this b/c you won't be able to access all of the forms you're generating from the scope... The last form in the repeat will shadow all the other ones.

Then inside the `ng-repeat` you can use `ng-form`. The purpose of this is so that each of the form controls in the `ng-repeat` has a local `FormController` with which to do the validation on.  All of these inner `ng-forms` will work with the parent `<form>` tag, to notify it that some element is invalid, dirty, etc.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons ng-form="innerForm">
    <td ng-class="{ 'has-error' : innerForm.firstName.$error.required && !innerForm.firstName.$pristine }">
      <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="person.firstName" maxlength="25" class="form-control" required />
    </td>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the ng-submit remain on the parent form?  When doing the validation do I reference the innerForm instead of myForm?

Comment: Yes, put the `ng-submit` on the parent form. I edited my example to show that you should reference the inner form for showing validation errors.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at your `ng-submit` ... That's not going to work properly if you use my example. The reason is that you want each form to be submitted individually based on your ng-submit.  I forget exactly if this works, but you can try generating multiple forms as you've done in your question, but assign the form a dynamic name:  `<form name="myForm{{$index}}">`

Comment: That works but the ng-submit on the parent form no longer works.  Will the ng-submit on the parent form work, or does it have to become an ng-click on the button?

Comment: Using my example and adding a button w/ng-click to submit the person would work. But now you're adding a button to each repeated element. I think you might want to try the dynamic form name approach instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you point me to where I could learn about the "dynamic form name approach"?